# Gerar coluna calculada baseada em regras (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho 2 dataframes, o de venda e o de comissão, preciso calcular a comissão em cima do valor da venda para cada loja e produto dentro de um período

**DF Venda**

```
Loja        object
Pedido      object
Produto     object
DataVenda   datetime64[ns]
ValorVenda  float64

venda = pd.DataFrame({
    'Loja': ['Matriz', 'Filial 1', 'Filial 2', 'Matriz', 'Matriz'],
    'Pedido': ['P001', 'P002', 'P003', 'P004', 'P005'],
    'Produto': ['Mesa', 'Mesa', 'Cadeira', 'Mesa', 'Armario'],
    'DataVenda': pd.to_datetime(['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05']),
    'ValorVenda': [100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 170.0, 200.0]
})
```

**DF Comissao**

```
Loja            object
Produto         object
Valor           float64
Comissão        float64
Data Inicial    datetime64[ns]
Data Final      datetime64[ns]

comissao = pd.DataFrame({
    'Loja': ['Matriz', 'Filial 1', 'Filial 2', 'Matriz', 'Matriz'],
    'Produto': ['Mesa', 'Mesa', 'Cadeira', 'Mesa', 'Armario'],
    'Valor': [100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 170.0, 200.0],
    'Comissão': [0.10, 0.15, 0.17, 0.05, 0.2],
    'Data Inicial': pd.to_datetime(['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05']),
    'Data Final': pd.to_datetime(['2023-01-31', '2023-02-28', '2023-03-31', '2023-01-31', '2023-02-28'])
})
```

[image: Dataframes]

Minha dúvida é, existe alguma maneira "fácil" de fazer isso e que permita aplicar mais regras posteriormente? Consegui fazendo assim, porém fica muito engessado nas mesmas regras e **existem casos onde o valor da venda pode ser `<=` e não precisa ser apenas `==` ao valor definido pela comissao**

```
def comissao(venda, comissao):
    comissao = comissao.loc[
        (
            (comissao['Loja'] == venda['Loja'])
            & (comissao['Produto'] == venda['Produto'])
            & (comissao['Data Inicial'] <= venda['DataVenda']) 
            & (comissao['Data Final'] >= venda['DataVenda'])
            & (comissao['Valor'] == venda['Valor'])
        ), 'Comissão'].values
    return comissao[0]*venda['Valor'] if(len(comissao) > 0) else 0
        
venda['Comissao'] = venda.apply(lambda linha: comissao(linha, comissao), axis=1)
```